# PHP preg_match strings in between quotations for entire file

Tags: php, parsing, preg-match

I've created a php file that I'm trying to parse data with. The file's content that I'd like to parse looks like this:

```
[Titles]
  hollywoodhd1 1 0 8046 0 919 PG-13 6712 1 identity_hd "(HD) Identity Thief" Disk 0 04/15/13 11/01/13 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 16000000 H3 16:9 0 0
  hollywoodhd2 3 0 8016 0 930 PG 5347 1 escapep_hd "(HD) Escape from Planet Earth" Disk 0 04/01/13 10/01/13 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 16000000 H3 16:9 0 0
  hollywoodhd3 1 0 8012 0 930 PG-13 5828 1 darkski_hd "(HD) Dark Skies" Disk 0 04/01/13 10/01/13 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 16000000 H3 16:9 0 0
```

The PHP that i've created:

```
<?php

foreach (glob("*.mov") as $filename)

$theData = file_get_contents($filename) or die("Unable to retrieve file data");
    // echo nl2br($theData); //- This will print the entire text-wrapped line breaks.

$Ratings = ['G', 'PG', 'PG-13', 'R', 'NR', 'XXX']; // - This doesn't do anything yet.

if (preg_match('!"([^"]+)"!', $theData, $m)){

        echo $m[1];
}

?>
```

QUESTION: I'd like to return the MOVIE TITLE : RATING, but the code that I have only returns a single movie title so far, (HD) Identity Thief. I have a long way to go so any guidance would be greatly appreciated. Is there a way to sort Movie Title : Rating, strictly by the Ratings?

Also, is there a way to have the PHP script search a directory, and sub folders for any ".mov" file extension, run the script for each file?

Comment: you've asked like three questions. to get a better answer, try rewording this to one single, succinct question. you can always ask more questions later.

Comment: @sgroves Sorry about that. This is my first question. I'll be sure to separate them in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I have so far, I haven't gotten the sorting part, since you don't say how you want it sorted...

```
<?php
header("content-type: text/plain");
function getInfo($string){
    $Ratings = ['G', 'PG', 'PG-13', 'R', 'NR', 'XXX']; // Used in the loop below
    $split = preg_split("/\"(.+)\"/", $string, -1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);
    $string = $split[1];
    preg_match("/(".implode("|", $Ratings).")\s/", $split[0], $matches);
    $rating = $matches[0];
    return ["title" => $split[1], "rating" => $rating];
}


$string = <<<String
[Titles]
  hollywoodhd1 1 0 8046 0 919 PG-13 6712 1 identity_hd "(HD) Identity Thief" Disk 0 04/15/13 11/01/13 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 16000000 H3 16:9 0 0
  hollywoodhd2 3 0 8016 0 930 PG 5347 1 escapep_hd "(HD) Escape from Planet Earth" Disk 0 04/01/13 10/01/13 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 16000000 H3 16:9 0 0
  hollywoodhd3 1 0 8012 0 930 PG-13 5828 1 darkski_hd "(HD) Dark Skies" Disk 0 04/01/13 10/01/13 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 0 16000000 H3 16:9 0 0
String;
$titles = explode("\n", $string);
// Remove the first line
unset($titles[0]);

foreach($titles as $title){
    $info = getInfo($title);
    echo "{$info["title"]} : {$info["rating"]}\n";
}
```

Then, here is the output that is returned:

> (HD) Identity Thief : PG-13
>   (HD) Escape from Planet Earth : PG
>   (HD) Dark Skies : PG-13

Comment: Is there a way to return only the title and the rating?

Comment: My apologies Ryan Naddy. Is there a way to display only the title and rating without showing the array. So it would only display, (HD) Identity Thief PG-13 etc. Not [0] => Array ( [title]...

Comment: Yeah, just loop through that array and display it how you want it.

Comment: I converted it to a function for you, take a look